# SOAP - Request Entity Too Large (413)

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

I am facing Issue When Making A request paragraph hum of a method Determined Web Service ( SOAP ) but This method accepted How hum parameter matrix , in which case this very large and Returns hum error when trying to call this method , the error in this case is : "Request Entity Too Large (413)"

I'm using Delphi XE2 and this follows my code

```
htprPrinc := THTTPRIO.Create(Self);
htprPrinc.WSDLLocation := Trim(WSDL);
htprPrinc.Service := SERVICE;
htprPrinc.Port := PORT;

SNDApi := (htprPrinc As IServiceAPILayer);
htprPrinc.HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout := 10000 * 120;
htprPrinc.HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout := 10000 * 15;
htprPrinc.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 10000 * 120;
htprPrinc.HTTPWebNode.MaxSinglePostSize := 99999999;
```

Answer (score 1):

A 413 error occurs when the request body is larger than the server is configured to allow. I'm not sure what server you are trying to connect to but here is another stack exchange post the covers some steps to resolve this issue: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2330

Comment: See if I'm right , you're saying then that an alteration should be done on the server that the Web Service so that it accepts a larger size ?

Comment: That is correct. Alternatively, you could try sending lest data in your request. Maybe breaking the request up into smaller requests is an option?

Comment: ok , thank you , I will contact the server administrator to see if I can achieve any result , thank you for your attention , come back here to post the solution we get